# Sort a list of strings based on 2 criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of strings.

I would like to sort them based on 2 criteria:

- from small length to large length
- if the length of 2 strings are same, then sort by `<` of string values

Does anyone know how to achieve that in Python?

I tried

```
def cmp(a,b):
    if len(a) < len(b):
        return -1
    elif len(a) > len(b):
        return 1
    elif a < b:
        return -1
    elif a > b:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

myList.sort(lambda x,y: cmp(x, y))
```

But it gave me an error `TypeError: sort() takes no positional arguments`.

Comment: It takes no positional args, only named args *e.g* `key=`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need all the branching. The pythonic way is to just return a tuple which will sort in the order of the tuple:

```
s = ['twenty', 'three', 'two','one',  'four']

sorted(s, key=lambda w: (len(w), w))
# ['one', 'two', 'four', 'three', 'twenty']
```